# Doubts sectioning a book

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, context

I have a book divided into chapters and I need to have some pages in the beginning, like a page with the title and so on.

- Book title and author (one page)
- Credits (after the title page)
- Dedicatory (one page, plus blank page)
- Author's note (one page, plus blank page)
- Prologue
- Chapter 1
  ...
- Chapter N
- Epilogue
- Closing comments

I have done all the chapters as `\start-stopchapter` pairs, including prologue and epilogue, but I have doubts about the other pages/sections.

Title page, dedicatory and author's note... which would be the best way of doing them? With a command? An environment?

About the Prologue/Epilogue... they are defined as chapters, but I would like them to have no numbering, would it be possible?

Finally, in the Table of Contents, I would like to have all chapters, including Prologue/Epilogue, but also Author's note and Closing comments. I think that this would depend on how I typeset those sections.

Here I provide a minimal example:

```
\setuppapersize[A5]

\setupindenting[always,small,first]

% Header / Footer
\setuppagenumbering[location={footer,right}]

% Chapters
\define[2]\CustomChapter
  {\dontleavehmode\framed[frame=off,width=broad,align=center]{#1.\\#2}}

\setuphead [chapter] [after={\blank[2*line]},before={\blank},command=\CustomChapter]


% Author's note and closing should have a blank line before title and two after
\setuphead [title] [after={\blank[2*line]},before={\blank},incrementnumber=list]


\starttext

% Title page
\startstandardmakeup
My title page
\stopstandardmakeup

% Author note
\starttitle[title={AUTHOR'S NOTE}]This is a note from the author.\stoptitle

% Chapters with Prologue and Epilogue
\startchapter[title={Prologue}]This is the Prologue.\stopchapter
\startchapter[title={One}]This is Chapter One.\stopchapter
\startchapter[title={Two}]This is Chapter Two\stopchapter
\startchapter[title={Epilogue}]This is the epilogue\stopchapter

% Closing Comments
\starttitle[title={CLOSING COMMENTS}]These are closing comments.\stoptitle

% Table of contents
\setupheadtext[content=CONTENTS]
\completecontent[criterium=previous]

\stoptext
```

This produces the structure I am looking for, but also reveals my problems, which are plenty, I am afraid:

- The title page is not being included in page count
- The command to render chapter titles seems to be used to render titles, it is ignoring my redefinition for titles.
- I do not know how to shut off numbering for the Prologue and Epilogue, which to me are chapters, but with no numbers. Maybe there is a better way to markup them.
- Author's note and Closing comments are not being shown in the Table of Contents.
- Now that I look closely... I am not sure if the Chapter titles are being centered in the page, they look somewhat out of place.

Comment: Yes, all is possible, but it **strongly** depends what **you** have done so far -- and there's not a single line of code, so we advise anything at the moment

Comment: Try telling us things like:  what macro package you're using (TeX, LaTeX, etc.); if LaTeX, what documentclass you're using; and a more precise idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I did tag the question as ConTeXt, but maybe the lowercase word 'context' is not clear enough. Would like to have an example which shows the problems I am facing, I hope to have it ready soon, with some new changes inspired bu Aditya's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my suggestions:

- **Book Titles**: `\startstandardmakeup ... \stopstandardmakeup`.
- **Credit/Dedication, etc**: `\starttitle ... \stoptitle`;

  If you want them in ToC, add `\setuphead[title][incrementnumber=list]`

Depending on how big the book is, and whether you need different numbering for frontmatter and bodymatter, you may also want to include all the material before Chapter 1 in `\startfrontmatter ... \stopfrontmatter` and the rest in `\startbodymatter .. \stopbodymatter`.

Comment: I'm working with this, although using '\startitle' and '\stoptitle' has surprised me... I have redefined the chapter head, using a command to render a custom chapter title, and the title environment seems to be using the redefined command.

Comment: This is because numbered and unnumbered heads at the same level are coupled. You may use `\setuphead[title][command=]` if you don't want this coupling.